# Aurelia binding on styled checkboxes

Tags: javascript, data-binding, aurelia, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic-UI with Aurelia and found that binding on Semantic styled checkboxes only works one way.

I've created a Plunker to demonstrate: http://embed.plnkr.co/YPyKT0dwubzDCqEPmEPx/preview

In the example, I'm using the checkboxes to filter an array. Is there a different method I should be using that would work with the styled checkboxes?

Comment: Do Semantic UI check boxes have a callback for when their values change?  Perhaps you can pass a method to call to update the value?

Comment: I've written a blog about creating custom elements for wrapping css frameworks here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Aurelia binding system is listening for the input's `change` and `input` events.  When these are fired the binding is refreshed.

The Semantic UI checkbox uses jquery to [trigger a change event](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/1.x/dist/components/checkbox.js#L261) when it updates the input's checked property.  For some reason the synthetic change event fired by jquery isn't caught by Aurelia which uses the standard `addEventListener` function to subscribe to events.

Here's a workaround:

Original code:

```js
$('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();
```

Workaround:

```js
$('.ui.checkbox').checkbox()
  .on('change', e => fireEvent(e.target, 'input'));

function createEvent(name) {
  var event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent(name, true, true);
  return event;
}

function fireEvent(element, name) {
  var event = createEvent(name);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Here's the updated plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/qG850rRZag0Vb8FM1HZP?p=info

Comment: Thank you, so much! Exactly what I needed.